# Fixed and variable size columns in variable size table

Tags: css, variables, width

I've looked all over for answers on how to do this, including dozens of answers on Stack Overflow that provide almost but not quite solutions.

I am trying to make a table/list with a number of options. Imagine a table with the following columns:

Delete: A simple icon. This must be a fixed width (because it uses an image)

Name: The name of the item in the list. This should fill the remaining available space, but if the text overflows, I want the ellipsis to appear.

Options A/B/C: You can imagine these are check boxes and also are a fixed with.

So on a wide table it'd look like this:

```
| X | Item 1 in the list               | A | B | C |
| X | Item 2                           | A | B | C |
| X | Item 3 has a pretty long name    | A | B | C |
| X | Item 4's name is long, realll... | A | B | C |
```

And on a short table (or say, after the window resized):

```
| X | Item 1 in the list     | A | B | C |
| X | Item 2                 | A | B | C |
| X | Item 3 has a pretty... | A | B | C |
| X | Item 4's name is...    | A | B | C |
```

If someone could provide a fiddle showing this in action, that'd be absolutely fantastic.

EDIT: Thank you so much Plymouth!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mmpce/).

These are the important styles:

```
table
{
    table-layout:fixed;
}

.col2
{
    width:auto;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Is this what you're after?